# Did my setting for checksum duration get overridden?

Tags: checksum

A site had a Checksum duration set to be 90 days (about a year ago). Client just asked us to look at some duplicates and we wanted to check the duration was still 90 days.

When I checked on the Misc page it 'showed' the checksum duration as 7 days.

So i reset at 62 days and took a look in the log_civicrm_settings.

I don't see any values between Feb 2015 and May 31 - so am unclear if the checksums only had a 7 day duration or not.

```
id  group_name  name    value   domain_id   contact_id  is_domain   component_id    created_date    created_id  log_date    log_conn_id log_user_id log_action
60  CiviCRM Preferences checksum_timeout    s:2:"90";   1   NULL    1   NULL    2015-02-27 12:47:18 3   2015-02-27 12:47:18 223174  3   Update
'60 CiviCRM Preferences checksum_timeout    s:2:"62";   1   NULL    1   NULL    2016-05-31 10:28:52 3   2016-05-31 10:28:52 3676071 3   Update
```

I had hoped i could look at past checksums but understand these don't exist in the db so no clues from that end. is there some other way i can look in to this?